# Can Azure Web App Service IIS return an HTTP redirect with just a path?

Tags: azure, redirect, iis

I inherited an Azure Web App Service setup where IIS is configured to fix URLs that incorrectly end in a `/`. Let's say the site has a page at path `/login`. If someone incorrectly links to `/login/`, IIS returns an HTTP redirect to `/login` . The configuration block is:

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)/$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This works as intended. But we want the HTTP response's `Location` header value to contain only the new path instead of a full URL (explanation at the end of the post). Instead of:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.example.com/login
```

…we want:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /login
```

We tried a few versions like the following. It has an input for a server variable that only contains the path, and the action uses a different capture group.

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)/$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.*)/$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

But the response still has the full URL. We even tried hard-coding the output like `url="/test"` and still got a full URL.

Can we stop IIS from adding the scheme and hostname to the Location value?

--

The reason we're doing this is to move this site to a new hostname without having to actually reconfigure the application and infrastructure. This application will become an origin behind an existing CDN. Pages will be reached at a new hostname. We do not want origin responses to ever include the original hostname. We have a workaround using the CDN, but changing origin behavior is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

An obsolete version of the HTTP 1.1 specifications (IETF RFC 2616) required a complete absolute URI for redirection. The IETF HTTP working group found that the most popular web browsers tolerate the passing of a relative URL and, consequently, the updated HTTP 1.1 specifications (IETF RFC 7231) relaxed the original constraint, allowing the use of relative URLs in Location headers.

Whether the Location header value of an HTTP response is a relative path or an absolute path depends on the URL format used in the redirection rule. If you use a relative URL in your redirect rule, the Location header value in the response will also be a relative path.

Have you tried the site using HTTP instead of HTTPS, and then redirecting, does the same problem occur?

There is a possibility that when a client makes a request to a website over HTTP, and the server redirects the client to HTTPS, the server sends a 3xx status code and a Location header in the response to indicate to the client that the new URL should be requested over HTTPS. If the Location header contains a relative path, the client will interpret the path relative to the current request URL. This can cause problems if the client's original request was over HTTP, but the server redirects the client to HTTPS. In this case, the relative path in the Location header will be interpreted as an HTTP URL, which may not be what the server intended.To avoid this problem, the server can send an absolute path in the Location header, which will ensure that the client requests the correct URL over HTTPS.

Also if it is not the reason above, it may be that your CDN rewrites the Location header to include its own protocol and hostname, but it depends on the configuration and rules of the CDN.

Comment: > Whether the Location header value of an HTTP response is a relative path or an absolute path depends on the URL format used in the redirection rule. If you use a relative URL in your redirect rule, the Location header value in the response will also be a relative path.

This doesn't seem to be true with this web server. As far as we can tell, the modified config outputs only a path. It looks like IIS is forcibly adding the rest.

Comment: > it may be that your CDN rewrites the Location header to include its own protocol and hostname, but it depends on the configuration and rules of the CDN.


We actually are currently using our "real" CDN, something outside Azure, to overwrite these problematic Location header values.